IIS Deployment -> aspnetcore -> .net 8.0 -> Page refresh -> Http Error 404 -> The resource you are looking for has been removed
i have a strange problem. we developed an asp.net core application ( we have just migrated from .net core 5 to .net core 8 ) and we host this application on an IIS server.
If we deploy our application to iis the application is working without problems.

But if we press the F5 Button for reloading following error is thrown

This problem is only on our production system, if we start our application with visual studio there is no problem.
I am desperate, because i don´t know why this error occurs.
Do you have tips for me, what can cause this error.
thanks for your help

Please try to enable the failed request tracing rule, and check the details.
